Return all values based on associated field
I have a list of classification systems called "GRIDCODES." Each "GRIDCODE" is associated with a province ("name"). And each province can have more than one GRIDCODE associated with it.
For instance, Kansas is defined by GRIDCODES '37', '41', '31', and '26'.

However, there are hundreds of other provinces around the world that also have '37', '41', '31', and '26' as "GRIDCODES."
I can write a clumsy filter that checks to see which other provinces have those codes: (GRIDCODE IN ('37', '41', '31', '26')). And that will get me the final product I want. 
However, I would like to streamline this process. Is there an expression that allows me to "return all the provinces whose GRIDCODES are those of Kansas?"

And do what with it, save it in a new field?
